# Remove all Rows with more than 2 Numbers in it

Tags: excel

I want to remove all the rows that contain more than 2 numerical numbers in the A column.

If the value in the A column contains more than 2 numerical numbers in it, then I want to remove it.

Can some one help me with this?

**UPDATE**

```
A           b      C      D
12tech
1pics
google9
panda555
jer9gf666
9tom
```

I want to remove the 1st, 4th,5th rows in the example, because each of those contain more than 2 numbers.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by numerical numbers?

Comment: Do you mean 2 digits (ie > 9)?

Comment: I think it means that column A looks like "abc", "123", "abc 123", "345 sdf" or "123 345" and he only wants to delete the row that where both bits are numbers.  Assuming I am right, the question I have is: what is the delimiter between the two bits?  And is there anything in column B and C or is all the data in A (in which case text to columns might be useful).  Finally, do we need a programmatic solution or is just a set of steps to follow enough?

Comment: @Hogan i have updated my question with a small example please check

Comment: @qaphla i have updated my question with a small example please check..

Comment: @JerryJeremiah i have updated my question with a small example please check

Comment: @Hogan yes yes :D its right. more than 9...  like 10..50..90...900.11000.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming row 1 is a header row and your actual data starts in row 2, put this formula in cell B2 and copy down:

```
=SUM(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},"")))>1
```

Then filter on column B for TRUE, delete those rows, and remove the filter

Answer (score 1):

There is no pure-formula way to delete the rows (you can write a VBA macro using regular expressions, but since you didn't say to use macros I'll avoid them), but here is one procedure to find and delete the rows:

1) let B1 be the following formula:

```
= MIN(
IFERROR(FIND("0",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("1",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("2",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("3",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("4",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("5",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("6",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("7",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("8",A1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("9",A1),999999)
)
```

2) fill down column B

3) let C1 be the formula

```
= MIN(
IFERROR(FIND("0",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("1",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("2",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("3",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("4",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("5",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("6",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("7",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("8",A1,B1+1),999999),
IFERROR(FIND("9",A1,B1+1),999999)
)
```

4) fill down column C

5) let D1 be the formula

```
=C1<999999
```

6) fill down column D

7) insert a row above the top data row, and set the new A1 = "name" and D1 = "filter"

8) let F1="filter" and F2=TRUE

9) select table (A2:D...), right click, advanced filter

10) set the Criteria range to be F1:F2 and hit OK